# reCAPTCHA V2 in Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151003) error

Tags: recaptcha, captcha, sitecore8

We are facing Below error in our initially development.

We’re getting an error for Google: once I tried to saved form.

```
We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request.
Your data may not have been correctly saved.
```

For more details please find the attached  files.
Current error

```
 Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Source: System    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri
address, WebRequest& request)    at
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)    at
Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Validators.RecaptchaResponseValidatorAttribute.ValidateFieldValue(IViewModel
model, Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)    at
Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Validators.DynamicValidationBase.IsValid(Object
value, ValidationContext validationContext)    at
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
value, ValidationContext validationContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object
container)    at
System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.<Validate>d__1.MoveNext()
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.SectionModelBinder.BindFieldCollection(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable`1
list)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)  
at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.UpdateCollection(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type
elementType)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)   
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)  
at
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.ModelBinders.FormModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)    at
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)    at
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)    at
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
controllerContext, String actionName)   4908 08:35:10 WARN  Web Forms
for Marketers: an exception 'The remote server returned an error:
(403) Forbidden.' has occured while trying to execute an action ''.
```

[image: Console Error]

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should clearly describe how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Proxy issue:

```
var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
var client = new WebClient();
var url = string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, response);
NetworkCredential netcredit = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
client.Credentials = netcredit;
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("proxyurl");
proxyObject.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
client.Proxy = proxyObject;
var result = client.DownloadString(url);
var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");
```